# Does WebView Control support design mode?

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-8, .net-4.5, microsoft-metro

I found that, WebView control (For Windows 8 Metro style app)  is the one that works same as the Web Browser control for Windows Form. Can I turn 'DesignMode' = ON of this Web View control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the MSHTML.dll in a Metro App and the WebView does NOT support HTML Editing.

So what is left is building it yourself or finding someone who did it for you. At the moment I am not aware of anyone having built an HTML editor for Metro apps.

A work-around might be to [try and use TinyMCE in a HTML5/javascript Metro App](http://win8review.com/2011/10/windows-8-metro-style-app-developer-journal/). The author of this article has tried it but hasn't succeeded yet.

Comment: No, not as far as I know. Desktop/WPF applications are just Windows 7 applications. Remember though that these will only run on Intel not on ARM machines!

Comment: Thanks Erno for the helpful answer.